# Add Reminder with container reminder with applescript

Tags: applescript, reminders

I have this script to get all current window of chrome tab urls and add them as reminders:

```
    set titleString to ""

tell application "Google Chrome"
    
    set tab_list to every tab in window 0 # get the tabs
    
    
    repeat with the_tab in tab_list # for every tab
        set the_url to the URL of the_tab # grab the URL
        set the_title to the title of the_tab # grab the title
        set titleString to titleString & the_url & " - " & the_title & "" # concatenate
        tell application "Reminders"
            set mylist to list "My Inbox"
            tell mylist
                make new reminder at end with properties {name:the_title, body:the_url}
            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
    
    
    
end tell
```

That is Amazing!

[image]

But now i want all those tabs to have one container reminder so it would be more orgainzed, like that:

[image]

So i tried this code:

```
    set titleString to ""

set my_container_name to "My Last Tabs"
tell application "Reminders"
    set mylist to list "My Inbox"
    tell mylist
        make new reminder at end with properties {name:my_container_name}
    end tell
end tell
delay 1
tell application "Google Chrome"
    
    set tab_list to every tab in window 0 # get the tabs
    
    
    
    repeat with the_tab in tab_list # for every tab
        set the_url to the URL of the_tab # grab the URL
        set the_title to the title of the_tab # grab the title
        set titleString to titleString & the_url & " - " & the_title & "" # concatenate
        tell application "Reminders"
            set mylist to list "My Inbox"
            tell mylist
                make new reminder with properties {name:the_title, body:the_url, container:reminder whose name is my_container_name}
            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
    
    
    
end tell
```

But then i get this error:

> Can’t get reminder whose name = "My Last Tabs".

I don't find any document about this, and can't find how to do this... i tried adding a delay after creating this first reminder, but it didn't help.

To investigate i tried a simpler script like that:

```
tell application "Reminders"
    set myList to list "My Inbox"
    
    set containerRminderTitle to "Container"
    set subReminderTitle to "Sub Task"
    
    
    tell myList
        make new reminder with properties {name:containerRminderTitle}
        make new reminder with properties {name:subReminderTitle}
    end tell
    set container of reminder subReminderTitle of myList to reminder containerRminderTitle of myList
    
end tell
```

And then i get this error:

> error "Reminders got an error: Can’t set container of reminder to
> reminder "Container" of list id
> "5E29149A-101E-4816-A1E8-078DBDA802E3"." number -10006 from
> container of reminder